# How to rerun an inline loop in ZSH on single line (bash like behavior)

Tags: bash, loops, zsh, inline-editing

I'd like to know if there is a way to get inline loops in zsh to behave like in bash.

I've started using zsh recently and so far I like it. There is one thing in zsh I would like to behave like in bash, inline loops.

I often run quick loops like so `for in a b c` -> hit enter -> `do` -> hit enter and so on...

When I recall the command/loop to change in zsh, lines are wrapped over multiple lines, but in bash it is just a single line.

ZSH initial run:

```
user@localhost > for i in {a..c}
for> do
for> echo ${i}
for> done
a
b
c
```

ZSH repeat < arrow up >:

```
user@localhost > for i in {a..c}
do
echo ${i}
done
```

BASH initial run:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ for i in {a..c}
> do
> echo ${i}
> done
a
b
c
```

BASH repeat < arrow up >:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ for i in {a..c}; do echo ${i}; done
```

Answer (score 8):

There is a lovely option mentioned in the [Zsh Guide](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide04.html) under Fancier Editing: it is the `singlelinezle` option; setting this causes "...editing to [be restricted to] one line," enabling the desired behavior that you mentioned in your question.

```sh
# without `singlelinezle` set
user% for a in a b c; do echo $a; done
# output:
# a
# b
# c
# <up-arrow>
user% for a in a b c; do echo $a; done

user% for a in a b c; do
for> echo $a; 
for> done
# output: 
# a 
# b
# c
# <up-arrow>
user% for a in a b c; do
echo $a
done

setopt singlelinezle
# with `singlelinezle` set
user% for a in a b c; do echo $a; done
# output:
# a 
# b
# c
# <up-arrow>
user% for a in a b c; do echo $a; done


user% for a in a b c; do
for> echo $a
for> done
# output:
# a
# b
# c
# <up-arrow>
user% for a in a b c; do\necho $a\ndone

unsetopt singlelinezle
```